# Adding a delete button to each item in jquery ui sortable list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I'm trying to adding a delete button to each item in jquery ui sortable list in rails. I can add items and the button is appears but when i click it, its refreshes page and all javascript parts becomes unavailable.

Here's what I've done;

Coffescript:

```
$ ->
  $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    revert: true
  });
  $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();

  $('#additem').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    text = $("#e2").val()
    $li = $('<li class=\'alert alert-info\' style="font-weight: bold;"/>').text(
          text).append(
          $('<a />', 'id' : 'delete', 'class': 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove', 'href': '#', 'style' : 'float: right;'))
    $('#sortable').append $li
    $('#sortable').sortable 'refresh'
    return

  $('#sortable #delete').click ->
    $(this).parent().remove()
    return
```

HTML(Rails):

```
  <h3>Questions</h3>
  <%= select_tag 'user', options_for_select(@questions.collect{ |q| [q.content] }), id: "e2", name: "add1" %>

  <a href="#" id="additem" class="btn btn-primary">Add Question</a><br />
  <ul id="sortable">

  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Part of is [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for).

The correct adding item script:

```
$('#additem').click (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  text = $("#e2").val()
  $li = $('<li class=\'alert alert-info\' style="font-weight: bold;"/>').text(text).append(
        $('<a data-remote="true" id=\"delete\" class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\" href=\"#\" style=\"float: right;\"></a>'))
  $('#sortable').append $li
  $('#sortable').sortable 'refresh'
  return
```

Also delete item function is wrong. Here is the working script:

```
$('#sortable').on 'click', '#delete', ->
  $(this).parent().remove()
  return
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add a button usig html this works as generated by rails**

```
<a href="/question/question_id" data-remote="true"  data-method="delete" data-comfirm="Are you sure?" role = "button" class="btn btn-remove">delete
</a>
```

**You forgot to put method: delete and remote: true during link generation**

Comment: It does not give any response. Javascript parts does not even broken. Nothing happens.